# Split a special character string using c#

Tags: c#

I have a string as below

```
"/calc 2 3 +"
```

how to split in such a way that i can get

```
str1="/calc"
str2= "2 3 +"
```

is there any method in c# does special character splitting?
Thanks!

Comment: what does more of your data look like? There is  not enough to see a pattern.

Comment: You need to post the rule here. Is this a one static string ? Do you want to take always what is before the first space and everything after it in two separate strings ? Please be Specific.

Comment: Sorry , the rule will be like, the first word will start with forward slash and second word will after the space of first word.

Answer (score 5):

If it's just that string and always split like you have it, then you can do this:

```
var x = @"/calc 2 3 +";
var str1 = x.Substring(0, 5);
var str2 = x.Substring(6);
```

Otherwise, no, there's not special thing that does it because you don't have a unique delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

Use IndexOf method to find the first occurrence of space character. And then use Substring method to split the string into 2.

Answer (score 1):

```
string strInput = @"/calc 2 3 +";

var list = strInput.Split(' ').ToList();

str1 = list[0];
str2 = String.Join(" ",list.RemoveAt(0));
```

Comment: Even though this works, the method provided by huseyint and roryap are much cleaner and concise

Comment: @FrancisLord Agreed they're probably more efficient too. But this is far more general!

Comment: Yes, this performs too many string operations/allocations for a trivial task like this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised that no one provided the most obvious answer - using one of the [`string.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda(v=vs.110).aspx) overloads that allows you to specify the maximum number of substrings to return:

```
string input = "/calc 2 3 +";
var result = input.Split(new[] { ' ' }, 2);
Debug.Assert(result.Length == 2 && result[0] == "/calc" && result[1] == "2 3 +");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do that. The easiest one is to use index of the first space.

```
var mystr = @"/calc 2 3 +";
int index= mystr.IndexOf(' ');
var str1 = mystr.Substring(0, index);
var str2 = mystr.Substring(index+1);
```

Also if there is any pattern in your text, you can also use RegEx

Answer (score 0):

```
string a = "/calc 2 3 +";
string[] array = a.Split(' ');

str1= array[0];
str2= string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", array[1], array[2], array[3]);
```